# Samba: Software caused connection abort

Tags: 14.04, samba, file-sharing, smb

I am trying to create samba file server (*Ubuntu 14.04*) on my local network,
I can connect to samba server from another *Ubuntu 14.04* and enter the shared folder as a **guest**, but after creating a directory I'm getting following error:

```
Software caused connection abort
```

The point is that when I re-enter the shared folder I can see the created directory! So I have required write and read permissions,

I have tried different forms of configuration in `smb.conf` with no success, 
even when I share a directory by right-clicking and selecting local network share from the context menu, I will face the same error!

Also when I do the same procedure using smbclient:

```
NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED making remote directory \test
smb: \> SMBecho failed (NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED). The connection is disconnected now
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two weeks, I finally solved it.

The problem is that the new version of `samba` has a mind-blowing bug,
so anyone who has a similar problem may want to use the following command to downgrade their samba:

```
sudo apt-get install samba=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 samba-common=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 \
  samba-libs=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 samba-common-bin=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2  \
  samba-dsdb-modules=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 python-samba=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2  \
  libldb1=1:1.1.16-1 python-ldb=1:1.1.16-1
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba#Software_caused_connection_abort) this might be caused by deactivation of SMB1. SMB1 is deactivated by default since Samba 4.11 (at least on Arch). Adding the following to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` might solve to error:

```
[global]
client min protocol = CORE
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is the answer that worked for me ! (ubuntu 20)

Comment: The same on [Manjaro](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/smb-problem-failed-to-mount-windows-share-software-caused-connection-abort/138022/6). Thank you!

Comment: On Xubuntu, I had to run `sudo apt install samba` first, because the configuration file didn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

In a security update (19 april 2016) a dependency has been forgotten. You have to update library libtalloc2 with 
`apt-get install libtalloc2`